# How should I modify the prototype to allow construction of a hash after the coderef?

Tags: perl, subroutine-prototypes

This is what I have:

```
use 5.14.0;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub my_func(&$) {
    my $coderef = shift;
    my %attribs = @_;
}
```

This is what I'd like to achieve:

```
my_func {
    print 1;
} first_attrib => "1",second_attrib => "2";
```

However, I receive the error `Too many arguments for main::my_func at x.pl line 12, near ""2";"`. How should I modify the prototype, so that the parameters after the coderef will be transformed into a hash?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you change `sub my_func(&$)` to `sub my_func(&%)` your code will work.

The problem is that `first_attrib => "1",second_attrib => "2"` isn't a hash ref, but a list. And as friedo pointed out a list can be assigned to a hash, though a list with an odd number of elements might produce unwanted results and will produce a warning with `use warnings`.

Alternatively you can change your code to

```
sub my_func(&$) {
    my $coderef = shift;
    my ($attribs) = @_;
}

my_func {
    print 1;
} {first_attrib => "1",second_attrib => "2"};
```

to achieve what you seem to want.

The reason why you must wrap `$attribs` in parens is that assigning an array to a scalar returns just the number of elements in the array. At this point `@_` is this array:

```
({first_attrib => "1",second_attrib => "2"})
```

with a hash ref as a single element.

```
($attribs) = @_;
```

tells perl to create an anonymous array with the scalar `$attribs` as its first element, and assign elements from `@_` to the anonymous array, element by element, thus making `$attribs` point at the hash ref in `@_`.

Comment: It's more accurate to say that `first_attrib => "1",second_attrib => "2"` is a *list*, and a list can be assigned to a hash.

Answer (score 3):

You need to realize the arguments to a Perl sub form a list. You use the first element of the argument list for the coderef and the remaining elements to form a hash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.14.0;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub my_func(&@) {
    my $coderef = shift;
    my %attribs = @_;
    $coderef->() for keys %attribs;
}

my_func {
    print 1;
} first_attrib => "1",second_attrib => "2";
```

Comment: ++, the code will work with the call as written, if the prototype is just changed to `(&@)`.

Comment: @hobbs: Or `(&%)`, which in my opinion would be more intuitive given what the OP wants to achieve.